# Dart Sort list by two properties

Tags: dart

I have a List with same objects.

And I would like two sort all of them by two properties

First name (from a to Z)

Second type (numbers by ascending, like 1,2,3...)

```
void main() {
  List<MyObject> list = List();
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #8'));
  list.add(MyObject('Banana', 'definition of type #2'));
  list.add(MyObject('Orange', 'definition of type #3'));
  list.add(MyObject('Kiwi', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #4'));
  list.add(MyObject('Orange', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #8'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #2'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #17'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Banana', 'definition of type #5'));
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #16'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #7'));

  for (MyObject _object in list) {
    print(_object.name + ' ' + _object.type);
  }

  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
    r"#'?.*",
  );

  list.sort((a, b) {
    int _a = int.parse(regExp.stringMatch(a.type).replaceAll('#', ''));
    int _b = int.parse(regExp.stringMatch(b.type).replaceAll('#', ''));

    return _a
        .compareTo(_b); //to get the order other way just switch `adate & bdate`
  });

  list.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
}

class MyObject {
  String name;
  String type;

  MyObject(this.name, this.type);
}
```

I want output like this,

```
Apple #1
Apple #8
Apple #16
Banana #2
Banana #5
...
```

I tried to use a regex method for parsing numbers (from 'definition of type #(number)')

But If I sort list by this, I could not sort list from a to Z (name's)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of maps in Dart - Second Level Sort in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177838/sort-a-list-of-maps-in-dart-second-level-sort-in-dart)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to sort once and define the sorting method so it compares the type if name are the same:

```
void main() {
  List<MyObject> list = List();
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #8'));
  list.add(MyObject('Banana', 'definition of type #2'));
  list.add(MyObject('Orange', 'definition of type #3'));
  list.add(MyObject('Kiwi', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #4'));
  list.add(MyObject('Orange', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #8'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #2'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #17'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Banana', 'definition of type #5'));
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #16'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #7'));

  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
    r"#'?.*",
  );

  list.sort((a, b) {
    int compare = a.name.compareTo(b.name);

    if (compare == 0) {
      int _a = int.parse(regExp.stringMatch(a.type).replaceAll('#', ''));
      int _b = int.parse(regExp.stringMatch(b.type).replaceAll('#', ''));

      return _a.compareTo(_b);
    } else {
      return compare;
    }
  });

  for (MyObject _object in list) {
    print(_object.name + ' ' + _object.type);
  }
}

class MyObject {
  String name;
  String type;

  MyObject(this.name, this.type);
}
```

Output:

```
Apple definition of type #1
Apple definition of type #8
Apple definition of type #16
Banana definition of type #2
Banana definition of type #5
Kiwi definition of type #1
Orange definition of type #1
Orange definition of type #3
Peach definition of type #1
Peach definition of type #2
Peach definition of type #4
Strawberry definition of type #7
Strawberry definition of type #8
Strawberry definition of type #17
```

Answer (score 6):

To do a complete comparison, you should implement **Comparable< MyObject >** which exposes a `compareTo()` method to sort by one ore more property.

See full example below :

```
void main() {
  List<MyObject> list = List();
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #8'));
  list.add(MyObject('Banana', 'definition of type #2'));
  list.add(MyObject('Orange', 'definition of type #3'));
  list.add(MyObject('Kiwi', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #4'));
  list.add(MyObject('Orange', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #8'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #2'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #17'));
  list.add(MyObject('Peach', 'definition of type #1'));
  list.add(MyObject('Banana', 'definition of type #5'));
  list.add(MyObject('Apple', 'definition of type #16'));
  list.add(MyObject('Strawberry', 'definition of type #7'));

  list.sort();
  for (MyObject _object in list) {
    print(_object);
  }
}

abstract class Comparable {
   int compareTo(Object obj){
   }
}

class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
  static final RegExp _regExp = RegExp(r'\D+');

  final String name;
  final String type;

  MyObject(this.name, this.type);

  @override
  int compareTo(MyObject other) {
    int result = name?.compareTo(other?.name) ?? 0;
    if (result == 0) {
      int type1 = int.tryParse(type?.replaceAll(_regExp, '') ?? 0);
      int type2 = int.tryParse(other?.type?.replaceAll(_regExp, '') ?? 0);
      result = type1.compareTo(type2);
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '$name $type';
}
```

it prints

```
Apple definition of type #1
Apple definition of type #8
Apple definition of type #16
Banana definition of type #2
Banana definition of type #5
Kiwi definition of type #1
Orange definition of type #1
Orange definition of type #3
Peach definition of type #1
Peach definition of type #2
Peach definition of type #4
Strawberry definition of type #7
Strawberry definition of type #8
Strawberry definition of type #17
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example in Dart that sorts by sector then position.

```
static sortBySectorPosition(List<Subclass> subclasses) {
      subclasses.sort((a, b) {
        if (a.sector! == b.sector!) {
          return a.position!.compareTo(b.position!);
        } else {
          return a.sector!.compareTo(b.sector!);
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine, but I'd recommend using the [sorted package](https://pub.dev/packages/sorted). It's pretty sure that it's the cleanest solution.

To make the example shorter, I'm going to assume that `MyObject` is the following class:

```dart
class MyObject {
  const MyObject(this.firstName, this.number);

  final String firstName;
  final int number;

  @override
  String toString() => '$firstName $number';
}
```

You can sort `Iterable<Person>` like this:

```dart
final list = [
  MyObject('Apple', 1),
  MyObject('Strawberry', 8),
  MyObject('Banana', 2),
  MyObject('Orange', 3),
  MyObject('Kiwi', 1),
  MyObject('Peach', 4),
];

final sortedList = list.sorted(
  [
    SortedComparable<MyObject, String>((person) => person.firstName),
    SortedComparable<MyObject, int>((person) => person.number),
  ],
);

print(sortedList);
```

Hope this helps!