# List api response text alphabetically flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

Hello this is where i call api :

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/apis/hisselist.dart';




class Hisseler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hisseler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hisseler> createState() => _HisselerState();
}

class _HisselerState extends State<Hisseler> {

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;
  Hisselist? hisseResult;

  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey xxxx'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          counter = result.result.length;
          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHisse();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Hisseler'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.separated(
              itemCount: counter,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                height: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].lastpricestr.toString()??""),
                    subtitle: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].text??""),

                  ),
                );
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result I get :
[image]

I want to sort stocks with their name alphabetically. how can I do this? Thanks for your help

My model file :

```js
/*
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<ResultClass> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"], result: json["result"].map<ResultClass>((x) => ResultClass.fromJson(x)).toList(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": result.map((x) => x.toJson()),
  };
}

class ResultClass {
  ResultClass({
    required this.rate,
    required this.lastprice,
    required this.lastpricestr,
    required this.hacim,
    required this.hacimstr,
    required this.text,
    required this.code,
  });

  double rate;
  double lastprice;
  String lastpricestr;
  double hacim;
  String hacimstr;
  String text;
  String code;

  factory ResultClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResultClass(
    rate: double.tryParse(json["rate"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    lastprice: double.tryParse(json["lastprice"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: double.tryParse(json["hacim"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}


 */

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<Result> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"],
    result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    this.rate,
    this.lastprice,
    this.lastpricestr,
    this.hacim,
    this.hacimstr,
    this.min,
    this.minstr,
    this.max,
    this.maxstr,
    this.time,
    this.text,
    this.code,
  });

  double? rate;
  double? lastprice;
  String? lastpricestr;
  String? hacim;
  String? hacimstr;
  dynamic min;
  String? minstr;
  dynamic max;
  String? maxstr;
  Time? time;
  String? text;
  String? code;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    rate: json["rate"].toDouble(),
    lastprice: json["lastprice"].toDouble(),
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: json["hacim"],
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    min: json["min"],
    minstr: json["minstr"],
    max: json["max"],
    maxstr: json["maxstr"],
    time: timeValues.map[json["time"]],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "min": min,
    "minstr": minstr,
    "max": max,
    "maxstr": maxstr,
    "time": timeValues.reverse[time],
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}

enum Time { THE_1809, THE_1808, THE_1805, THE_1810, THE_1759, THE_1755 }

final timeValues = EnumValues({
  "17:55": Time.THE_1755,
  "17:59": Time.THE_1759,
  "18:05": Time.THE_1805,
  "18:08": Time.THE_1808,
  "18:09": Time.THE_1809,
  "18:10": Time.THE_1810
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap!;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a sort function before you return the hisseResult like so:

Assuming you get a json or class object in a list like this:

```
//SAMPLE LIST
List<Map> result= [
  {"text": 'B', "lastprice": 10},
  {"text": 'Y', "lastprice": 10},
  {"text": '2', "lastprice": 10},
  {"text": 'X', "lastprice": 10},
  {"text": 'A', "lastprice": 10},
  {"text": '1', "lastprice": 10}
];
```

in your function callHisse(), do a sort like this:

```
counter = result.length;
result.sort((a, b) => a["text"].compareTo(b["text"]));
hisseResult = result;
```

This sorts alphabetically and numerically.

This is a related post: [Sort a list of maps in Dart - Second Level Sort in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177838/sort-a-list-of-maps-in-dart-second-level-sort-in-dart)
And the official docs.: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html

Hope it helps.

---

EDIT:
In response to your comment about Model sorting.

Copying the models for Hisselist and Result you have in your code, the following should work.

Remember you are doing the sort in the Result List, and not the Hisselist model.

The variables text can be null in your model code, thefore we need to check if it is, then use an empty string for the sort "".

```
class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<Result> result;
}

class Result {
  Result({this.text, this.lastprice});
  final double? lastprice;
  final String? text;

  @override
  toString() => "{text:$text}";
}

  final dummyData = Hisselist(success: true, result: [
    Result(text: "B"),
    Result(text: "Y"),
    Result(text: "2"),
    Result(text: "X"),
    Result(text: "A"),
    Result(text: "1")
  ]);

  List<Result> result = dummyData.result;
  result.sort((a, b) => (a.text ?? "").compareTo(b.text ?? ""));
  print(result);
```

in this examble this retuns: [{text:1}, {text:2}, {text:A}, {text:B}, {text:X}, {text:Y}]

Comment: I tried this before but i get this error : error: The method 'sort' isn't defined for the type 'Hisselist'. Hisselist is my model

Comment: Hi!, check out my edit in the post above to implement sorting in your Result Model list.

Comment: Really sorry, i'm confused. where will i add this codes?

Comment: in your callHisse() function, in setState just before hisseResult = result;  insert the sorting result.sort((a,b)=>........) like above, you just need to add that line, the rest was for teaching and example purposes.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, now im running the app on simulator. will let you know the result. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort() method of the dart List to sort a list lexicographically (alphabetically).

Let's assume you have a list i.e.

```
List<Model> list = [
  Model(name: xyz, id: 1),
  Model(name: abc, id: 2),
  Model(name: mno, id: 3),
];
```

we want to sort the list using "name" alphabetically. So for that, we have to take this step.

```
var sortedList = list.sort((model1, model2) => {
  model1.name.compareTo(model2.name);
});
```

Here the sortedList is the list that you want to show.

Comment: I added my model file. Can you rewrite your code again according to my model.

Comment: Get the sorted list by doing this.
var list =  hisseResult.result.sort((res1, res2) => {
    return res1.text.compareTo(res2.text);
});

Comment: Where will I add this in my code?

Comment: in the build method, don't forget to change the list in the itemBuilder. use this sorted list there.